# How to generate a Aho-Corasick hash

Tags: algorithm, aho-corasick

I have recently started developing an open source anti virus software, although the hashes are generated with the Aho-Corasick algorithm.

I would love to know how to generate Aho-Corasick hashes from executables, as I have found barely any information on the internet regarding this

Comment: What makes executables different from strings?  Why can't you read the executable as a string?

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to this area, the virus database is preformatted as Aho-Corasick hashes, hence I need to be able to generate them somehow

Comment: No worries.:)  The point I was trying to make was this:  if you know how to create hashes from strings, why not just read in the executable as a string (of data) and perform the hashing algorithm on that string?  Note, I'm not referring to the String data type, but, rather an abstract notion of "string."

Comment: [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%2DCorasick_string_matching_algorithm) is an algorithm for searching for any one of a set of strings. The algorithm builds a finite automaton (FA) and then feeds the FA the data being searched. It sounds like the database contains the constructed FA; in that case you'd need to figure out how the FA is represented in the database, implement a program to read the database and simulate the FA, and feed it the files you're scanning.

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

```
private static String readFile(String path) throws IOException {
  FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
  try {
    FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
    MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
    /* Instead of using default, pass in a decoder. */
    return Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
  }
  finally {
    stream.close();
  }
}
```

Then you can use, following to get MD5 hash

```
byte[] bytesOfMessage = readFile("filepath").getBytes("UTF-8");
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
String thedigest = Arrays.toString[md.digest(bytesOfMessage)];
```

Comment: Application developers should only take notice of the methods defined in this MessageDigest class; all the methods in the superclass are intended for cryptographic service providers who wish to supply their own implementations of message digest algorithms. (source: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html)

Comment: If I understand the question, there's a specific hash format James is looking to support, in which case MD5 isn't useful.

Comment: @Andy He has not made any effort, in showing what he tried. So I showed an example, on how he should do that. In my example I created a MD5 hash for a file. I could have elaborated more on how to make custom hash for messagedigest, but I was uncertain if he even understands Java. MD5 does not need to be useful, it is just space filler.